# it is a good idea to turn on heating at the end of every air conditioning cycle at home for keeping filters clean against molds?

Tags: air-conditioning, mold

The question is: 
it is a good idea to turn on heating at the end of every air conditioning cycle at home for keeping filters clean against mold?
Or is there any other way keeping filters clean due to condensation? I think that heating will kill them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Your filter is before the fan, before the cooler. Condensation occurs far after that.